# Is possible in android to pan/drag a layout?

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout, pan

I am trying to pan a `RelativeLayout` with child `View`s, using gesture `onScroll` event, but I do not get the result that I desire.  I have tried to move the children, but nothing works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Explain what the desired result is, and what result you get. it's is hard to give an answer with this little information.

Comment: I desire to pan Relativelayout as a zoomable imageview but layout seems to move a bit and nothing else. If is not clear please tell me.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225265/pinch-zoom-and-pan/20226476#20226476

I hope it helps.